# Необходимо из int rgba, в котором содержится цвет в формате rgba вытащить в отдельные переменные все цвета и значение канала альфа

Tags: java, битовые-операции

На вход дается `int rgba`, в котором хранится цвет в формате rgba. Нужно в отдельных методах вытащить по отдельности все цвета и значение параметра альфа. И ровно наоборот, из 4 различных `int` собрать полностью цвет в rgba.

[image: rgba в памяти]

Я понимаю, что нужно это делать через битовые операции, но я не до конца уверен. Мне кажется это должно выглядеть как-то так:

- Альфа: `return (rgba & 0xFF)`
- Синий цвет : `return ((rgba & 0xFF00) >> 8`
- Зеленый цвет: `return ((rgba & 0xFF0000) >> 16`
- Красный цвет: `return ((rgba & 0xFF000000) >> 24`

А чтобы собрать rgba обратно:

```
rgba = 0;
rgba = (red << 24) | (green << 16) | (blue << 8) | (alpha)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом всё нормально, только для вычисления красного цвета имеет смысл воспользоваться беззнаковым сдвигом `>>>`:

```java
static int red(int rgba) {
    return (rgba & 0xFF000000) >>> 24;
}
```

Или же сначала применить сдвиг, а затем наложить маску:

```
static int red_signed(int rgba) {
    return rgba >> 24 & 0xFF;
}
```

Сравнение результатов для `rgba = 0xFABBCC33;`:

```java
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(rgba) + " -> unsign red: " + Integer.toHexString(red(rgba)));
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(rgba) + " -> signed red: " + Integer.toHexString(red_signed(rgba)));
```

Output:

```
fabbcc33 -> unsign red: fa
fabbcc33 -> signed red: fa
```